# Why comparing an Object with a numeric literal compiles in Java?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I'm wondering why the following code snippet compiles in Java 7 without a warning

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", 0);
if (map.get("key") != 0) {
    System.out.println("what?!");
}
```

Studying the generated bytecode reveals that the compiler boxes the `0` used in the `if` statement to an instance of `Integer` (using `Integer.valueOf(0)`) and then compares it with the result of the `get` using reference equality. Surprisingly enough the code doesn't print anything because instances of small integers are reused. But if one replaces `0` with say, `4096` in both cases, the program prints "what?!"

But my question is not why this code works or doesn't - it's an offense to write such a code. I'd rather expect the compiler to reject it completely! Why doesn't it?

Comment: It looks like you understood what happens. So your question is a little surprising. The compiler doesn't reject the code because of what you explained before.

Comment: You asked an answer, somehow.

Comment: To be able to compare `Integers` using `==` can be convenient, so it's allowed. For legacy reasons, `map.get` returns an `Object` (and not a `V`).